# .NET SDK wouldn't show up on Fedora 36

Tags: fedora, .net

Installed .NET and its dependencies by running

`sudo dnf install dotnet`

After executing

`dotnet --info`

```
Host (useful for support):
  Version: 6.0.6
  Commit:  7cca709db2

.NET SDKs installed:
  No SDKs were found.

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.6 [/usr/lib64/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.6 [/usr/lib64/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

To install additional .NET runtimes or SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
```

it showed no installed SDKs.

Reinstalled (it was installed) dotnet-sdk-6.0.

`sudo dnf reinstall dotnet-sdk-6.0`

Reinstalled successfully, still won't show up.

Even tried

`sudo dnf install dotnet-sdk-6.0.x86_64`

No result after installation.

`dotnet --info`

Shows that no SDKs are installed, even though they are.

Please help me or show me my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

This happened because of package conflict.

Solution:

1. `sudo dnf remove -y packages-microsoft-prod`
2. `sudo dnf autoremove -y dotnet-sdk-3.1`
3. `sudo dnf install dotnet-sdk-3.1`

[Explanation](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/5746) by dagood